# Did Stack Exchange delete my question from my "Deleted Recent Questions" page?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Several Months ago I contacted the Stack Exchange team asking them to disassociate my name from [a question I had posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642958/why-are-pointers-used-in-c).

My request was denied, and they left a message explaining why:

> Hello,
>
> The question is already deleted and not visible to other users, so there is no reason for it to be further disassociated from your name.
>
> Regards,
> Stack Overflow Team

*Ok. thats reasonable*, I thought, and went on.

A few weeks later however, I went to view my questions, which I rarely do. I clicked on the "recently deleted questions" link under my visible questions, and was surprised to find that it was empty. The page simply said:

> No deleted recent questions

This was odd due to the fact that my deleted question had just been there a few days ago. It was the one I gave a link to early in my post- which had been there since late July, *which was over two months ago*.

Why is my deleted question gone? I know the link says "Deleted Recent Questions", but how long is "recent"? Surely two months is not considered recent.

This is why I think that Something else happened to my questions. But the statement I showed above from the Stack Exchange team clearly shows my request was denied, and further more I asked for disassociation not deletion.

What happened to my question? Did the Stack Exchange team do something to it, or am I committing *[Post hoc ergo propter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)*
?

Comment: they key may be *"No deleted **recent** questions"*. it's still deleted and associated to you.

Comment: Recent is 60 days. You asked that question on July 28, which is well past the 60-day mark and won't show up in that list.

Comment: You delete the question yourself. As it can be seen by the banner on the question. The question is soft deleted and can still be viewed by 10k users and moderators. You don't see the delete question under "Deleted Recent Questions" because 2 months isn't that "recent" anymore.

Comment: @animuson Ah, thank you. Thats what I was looking for. It was just a matter of the definition of "recent".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be fair, it doesn't seem that this is documented anywhere in the help center, only piece-wise on meta, and actually defined a *long* time ago (2013) on MSE

> we're showing a link (visible only to profile owners and moderators) on the Questions and Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently limited to those posted in the past 60 days - [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/178816)

Comment: Well maybe it would be a good idea to add this to the help center, as I had no idea about it.